# Window functions or other to filter out events

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that is constantly loaded with events from "sensors" connected to a server. The server sends events which we load into a bigquery table. I want to query the table every 30 minutes and list all sensors which haven't sent a heartbeat and also add a column with the timestamp when the last heartbeat was received.
My table looks like this:

```
sensor, event_timestamp, received_timestamp, event, level, message
sensor1, 2021-04-26 03:57:56.964 UTC, 2021-04-26 03:57:57.964 UTC, heartbeat_lost, error, "heartbeat lost for 20 mins"
sensor2, 2021-04-26 03:57:56.964 UTC, 2021-04-26 03:57:57.964 UTC, heartbeat_lost, warning, "heartbeat lost for 5 mins"
sensor1, 2021-04-26 03:36:56.964 UTC, 2021-04-26 03:36:57.964 UTC, status, heartbeat, null
sensor2, 2021-04-26 03:51:56.964 UTC, 2021-04-26 03:51:57.964 UTC, status, heartbeat, null
......
sensor3,..
sensor100,...
sensor1, 2021-04-26 02:57:56.964 UTC, 2021-04-26 02:57:57.964 UTC, heartbeat_lost, error, "heartbeat lost for 20 mins"
```

Desired result. I would like to know what sensors haven't received a heartbeat and when the latest heartbeat was received. Something like this:

```
sensor, event_timestamp, received_timestamp, event, level, message, last_heartbeat_timestamp
sensor1, 2021-04-26 03:57:56.964 UTC, 2021-04-26 03:57:57.964 UTC, heartbeat_lost, error, "heartbeat lost for 20 mins", 2021-04-26 03:36:56.964 UTC
```

I have been trying to add the last_heartbeat_timestamp with a window-function but I have difficulties knowing how to only get the last event with a heartbeat. Also tried to first query the error messages and the left joining a query with the heartbeats but I only want one row from the heartbeats - the last one where error_event_timestamp > heartbeat_event_timestamp.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `last_value`: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#last_value

Comment: Thanks for the input Sergey, but wouldn't that give the oldest row? There are so many events from one sensor and there are many heartbeats lost and I just need to find the event when we got the latest heartbeat before the error or did I misunderstand your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Group by sensor and then get the latest event, also check if it fits in a recent window time by getting the difference between two timestamps:

```sql
SELECT 
    sensor,
    MAX(event_ts) AS last_event_ts,
    IF( TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP('2021-04-28 23:50:00'), MAX(event_ts), SECOND) < 2, MAX(event_ts), NULL) AS recent_event 
FROM sensors
GROUP BY sensor
```

Fully working example with fake data similar to your structure:

```sql
WITH sensors AS (
    SELECT 
        'sensor-1' AS sensor,
        TIMESTAMP('2021-04-28 23:50:00') AS event_ts
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        'sensor-1' AS sensor,
        '2021-04-28 23:51:00' AS event_ts
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        'sensor-1' AS sensor,
        '2021-04-28 23:52:00' AS event_ts
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        'sensor-1' AS sensor,
        '2021-04-28 23:54:00' AS event_ts

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        'sensor-2' AS sensor,
        '2021-04-28 23:40:00' AS event_ts
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        'sensor-2' AS sensor,
        '2021-04-28 23:41:00' AS event_ts
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        'sensor-2' AS sensor,
        '2021-04-28 23:42:00' AS event_ts
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        'sensor-2' AS sensor,
        '2021-04-28 23:54:13' AS event_ts

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        'sensor-3' AS sensor,
        '2021-04-28 23:40:00' AS event_ts
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        'sensor-3' AS sensor,
        '2021-04-28 23:41:00' AS event_ts


)

SELECT 
    sensor,
    MAX(event_ts) AS last_event_ts,
    IF( TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP('2021-04-28 23:50:00'), MAX(event_ts), SECOND) < 2, MAX(event_ts), NULL) AS recent_event 
FROM sensors
GROUP BY sensor
```